# Modifying all $scope.thing except one

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, dom, angularjs-scope

I have a `ul` that is populated with `li` made with an `ng-repeat = "thing in things"`. Each `li` has a `true` or `false` value defined by `$scope.isTrue = true;`. When a user clicks a `li` I want to change its `$scope.isTrue` value to `false`. If a user clicks a different `li` I want to change *its* `$scope.isTrue` value to `false` and change any other ones that may be `false` to `true`.

Here is my code so far (http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/8401/):

html:

```
<ul>                                         
  <li ng-repeat="thing in things" >                 
    <p ng-click="changeVal()">{{isTrue}}</p>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Angular:

```
$scope.isTrue = true;

$scope.changeVal = function() {
  if (this.isTrue == true) {
    $scope.isTrue = true;           //I try to change them all to true
    this.isTrue = false;            //but nothing happens.
  } else if (this.isTrue == false) {
    $scope.isTrue = true;
    this.isTrue = true;
  }
};
```

http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/8401/

The goal is to have one `false` value at a time. Thanks for the help.

Comment: also "Each li has a true or false value defined by `$scope.isTrue = true;`" modole `things` is an array but `$scope.isTrue` is not

Comment: What is `this.isTrue` doing here? `this` in a controller references the instance of the controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why not doing something like that :

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
<ul>                                         
  <li ng-repeat="(key,val) in things" >                 
    <p ng-click="changeVal(key)">{{val}}</p>
  </li>
</ul>
</div>

var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);
function MyCtrl($scope) {    
    $scope.things = { 
        0: true, 
        1: true, 
        2: true
    }

  $scope.changeVal = function(key) {
    $scope.things[key] = false
    for (k in $scope.things){
        if (k!= key && $scope.things[k] == false){
          $scope.things[k] = true
        }
    }
  };
}
```

See the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/87mnqLm7/1/)